# Black Magic/Kala Jadu/ Pilli Soonyam are real?

Tags: temple, tantra

As I know, due to jealousy, or some base cause, the *Tantriks* use cheap tactics to overcome the adversaries, which can ruins one's life .

Also I heard that if someone is affected by *Black Magic* then they should under go *Parikaram* to remove the Black magic applied on them.

Does something like black magic exist in this millennia(kaliyuga) ?

Comment: Those who use Tantric practices for self-indulgence and for harming others follow the Vamachara Tanra path. Contrary to popular misconception Tantra itself isn't bad by itself. We don't know for sure if black magic works. It is similar to us not knowing for sure if attaining super human yogic powers is possible. Though there is active research in that domain. Meditation and Yoga are hot domains to research on for neuroscientists in the west.

Comment: The fact is that black magic works.

Comment: By Sudarsana's grace I did a sudarsana homam for my friend in Hosur on Nov 1   2015. A ghost appeared in the homa kundam which was the back magic kept on his family. Now  he is relieved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Black magic is real and is  mentioned in Vedas itself.

Quoting from [this](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Atharvaveda) page:

**Core of Atharva Veda**

> The subject matter of the Samhitā of this Veda has no systematic
>   division in the first twelve kāṇḍas. The last two again, deal with
>   miscellaneous topics. However, there are eight topics that are
>   covered:
>
> ```
> 1.Bhaisajya: diseases, their causes and cures
> 2.Āyusya: supplications for longevity
> 3.Paustika: worldly progress and welfare
> 4.Ābhicārika: destroy or harm enemies who obstruct progress
> 5.Prāyaścitta: expiatory rites
> 6.Rājakarma: political system
> 7.Brahmanya : nature of Brahman, the Absolute.
> ```

**.....Abhicarika Suktas**

> The Ābhicāraka Suktas are aimed to destroy or harm enemies who
>   obstruct our progress or try to destroy us. This is said to be
>   achieved by pleasing or appeasing certain deities or spirits and
>   getting one’s wishes fulfilled through them. This technique is called
>   ‘yātu’ or ‘kṛtyā.’ The number of such suktas is rather large.
>   Destruction of one’s enemies including the lovers of one’s spouse,
>   annihilation of evil spirits, mesmerizing others through whom one can
>   get one’s desires fulfilled are some of the topics dealt with in these
>   suktas. **The word ‘kṛṣṇendrajāla’ is sometimes used to indicate the
>   type of black-magic rites depicted here**.

Comment: Is it adharma to do such things? It would be amazing to mesmerize others to seal business deals through this, but the mere thought feels like something is wrong in doing this.

Comment: I think you are talking about Vashikarana .. Yes, without having sufficient reasons one should do that to others .. suppose a wife has gone astray or a husband, then it is not Adharma to employ Vashikarana in those cases .. @Shashwat