# Do any Hindu scriptures condemn magick? Is the practice of magick by Wiccans using Hindu deities legitimate?

Tags: practice, ganesha, other-religions, kali

Witchcraft has been one of the most controversial issues in the West. Abrahamic religions such as Judaism, Christianity & Islam  consider it a sin against God but what does Hinduism say about it? Can a Hindu indulge in sorcery?

Also certain Wiccans (adherents of the Wicca religion, a Western pagan tradition that developed in the twentieth century that involves the practice of witchcraft) perform spellwork using the deities of various ancient religions including Hinduism (Lord Ganesha and Goddess Kali are the most used deities from Hinduism in Wicca). Is this practice legitimate?

Update: Seeing some of the comments, I wish to clarify Wicca is not black magick. In the [Wiccan Rede](https://wicca.com/celtic/wicca/rede.htm), it is stated:

> An it harm none, do what thou wilt'' (''Do what you will, so long as it harms none'').

Comment: I think this depends on 1) the exact definition of “witchcraft”, 2) the purpose of the ritual, 3) the laws in your country regarding such practises and 4) the context of Hindu (as in, which speficic sect/religion). For example, I don't think Dharma-śāstra "forbids" any ritual unless of course your intentions are incompatible with the law or the rules of your current religous/spiritual affliation.

Comment: Wicca or Goetia- What are these ?

Comment: @Rickross https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicca

Comment: @Rickross Types of pagan witchcraft

Comment: "Note: Certain Wiccans practice magick using the help of Hindu deities such as Lord Ganesha " - Is this mentioned in the links you provided ?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Actually no. You have to visit some Wiccan websites then.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury - Then i think you should remove that part , Ganesha is depicted as Brahman in Hindu scripture.And isn't associated with magic or similar sort of things.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar What part?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar http://hindudharmaforums.com/showthread.php?6633-Wiccans-who-show-appreciation-or-venerate-worship-Hindu-Deities

Comment: @SwiftPushkar http://wildhunt.org/2010/06/hinduism-indo-paganism-and-cultural-appropriation.html

Comment: There the author is speculating about Ganesha Yantra . Yantras are not part of magic or Witchcraft. Information from such blogs are highly unreliable and often portray  or link Hindu God and Goddesses in negative manner. They are not valid sources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63171/discussion-between-surya-kanta-bose-chowdhury-and-swiftpushkar).

Comment: @moonstar2001 Why not?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkBcaIMcckI

Comment: @moonstar2001 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkBcaIMcckI

Comment: it is not condemned but unlawful practice is wrong. done for genuine reasons not wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a verse that says that black magic (using roots) is a punishable offence.

> Manu Smriti 9.290. For all incantations intended to destroy life, for
>   magic rites with roots (practised by persons) not related (to him
>   against whom they are directed), and for various kinds of sorcery, a
>   fine of two hundred (panas) shall be inflicted.

Also here is a verse that says that performing black magic using roots ( **abhichAro mulakarma cha** is the sanskrit used in the original verse) is a minor sin:

> Manu Smriti 11.63. Superintending mines (or factories) of any sort,
>   executing great mechanical works, injuring (living) plants, subsisting
>   on (the earnings of) one’s wife, sorcery (by means of sacrifices), and
>   working (magic by means of) roots, (and so forth),....  (are all)
>   minor offences, causing loss of caste (Upapataka)

So, black magic is condemned, not sure about witchcraft etc. However, using certain forms of [black magic is present in the Vedas itself](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11037/4732). Where they are used to subdue powerful and evil enemies.

Comment: then why do they provide the process of abhichara? :)

Comment: Because sometimes we have to subdue bad people using such means. @RakeshJoshi